# Check if mysql user exists in bash script, getting error

Tags: mysql, bash, exists

I am working on a bash script to check if a mysql user exists, with following commands:

```
checkuser=`mysql -u $mysqlroot -p$rootpw -e "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$user_name') ;"`
lastchr=${checkuser#${checkuser%?}}
if [ $lastchr == 1 ] ; then
      clear
      echo "ERROR: mysql user exists"
fi
```

My problem is, that the terminal always gives me following feedback:

```
/etc/hosting: line 775: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/etc/hosting: line 775: `checkuser=`mysql -u $mysqlroot -p$rootpw -e "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$user_name') ;"`'
```

I tried with escaping the "(" and ")", but I didn't success.

What am I doing wrong? I tried all different kinds of escaping, single quotes, ... and it didn't help.

Kind regards

EDIT:
because maybe needed, previous lines:

```
echo "creating mysql user ..."
echo ""
read -p "enter username: " user_name

if [[ -z "$user_name" ]] ; then
      clear
      echo "username mustn't be empty!"
      create_mysql_user    # calls function again
fi

# check username length
if [ ${#my_user} -gt 16 ] ; then
      clear
      echo "ERROR: the username mustn't be longer than 16 characters"
      create_mysql_user
fi
```

Comment: What are the preceding lines?

Comment: I can execute your checkuser-command in bash and with /bin/sh - both without errors. Ist there maybe a '(' in your password? (but even then it works on my machine). How does your shebang look like? "#!/bin/bash"? or "#!/bin/sh"? Try calling your script with "bash /etc/hosting".

Comment: set -x will tell you what you're doing wrong. You'll be able to see exactly what is being run.

Comment: Replave the backtics with `$(mysql ... ;")`, it will make further debugging and escaping easier

Comment: You are mixing my_user and user_name

Comment: You should reconsider the username checks: when user_name is empty (-z), you call `create_mysql_user` again... When it is finished you script will continue with the check on the username length and will call mysql again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but still searchable on internet. I would like to answer it because it doesn't have a proper answer.

To check the existence of mysql user using bash, you can use the following package jq to transform the query result to readable output as list of users in array format:

```
 # Get list of all sql users
 sql_users=$(mysql -e "SELECT USER FROM mysql.user;" | jq -rR .)


 check_sql_user=$(echo "${sql_users}" | grep "username_to_check")

 if [[ -z "${check_sql_user}" ]]; then

  echo "No user found"
  # Call create user here
 else
  echo "User found"

 fi
```